# How to generate the password with permutation of string

Tags: java, passwords, generator

I want to build a very basic password generator in Java. I have all the characters I need set up in a String. I want to generate all possible permutations of the characters in the string and the length of password would be 1-256 characters.

Edit, people wanted some code:

```
String ascii = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!#$%&'()*+.-/:;<=>?@[]^_{|}~";
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ascii.length(); j++) {
            for (int k= 0; k < ascii.length(); k++) {
                System.out.print(ascii.charAt(k));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

This is what I have so far and I know it doesn't work.  The `System.out.println` on the bottom is to create a new line for every password it generates.

Edit 2, I feel that this is being misread as looking to generate a random password.  I am trying to generate a list of every password I can humanly generate.

Comment: There needs to be a `homework` tag to easily identify questions like this

Comment: @Isaac there used to be, it wasn't good. (see also [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated))

Comment: With a space of 90 characters and 256 possible spots to them in produces a possible language of... a number that is over 500 digits long (too long for me to put in the comment).  What you ask is a bit impractical.

Comment: I understand that it is impractical but I would like to still try to write it for testing.  I feel I am missing the basic code that should be obvious to me.  I just need to know how to write it to a string and not repeat anything that was written already.

Comment: You might try with just the 4 character ones first - that's only 65 million. Each additional character multiplies the space by 90. That gets big fast.

Comment: Very good point.  I did the math earlier to see how many combinations I could get earlier and it was pretty high.  I also plan to save this to a text document so it might be a little bit big.

Comment: If we're not concerned about practicality, you could try doing it recursively—run through all 90 characters per length 1–256 (which you would itself run through a loop)…but you'll probably run out of memory…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you I guess. Let me know if you need any modification.Enjoy, This will generate all permutation of what you have. Not sure if you are trying to hack some password, lol
I have added both permutation and combination method. Please use according to your need.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author Ashish Tyagi
 */
public class Stackoverflow {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        //String ascii = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!#$%&'()*+.-/:;<=>?@[]^_{|}~";
        String ascii="abc";
        for(int i=1;i<=ascii.length();i++){
        combin(ascii.substring(0, i), new StringBuffer(), i);
        combin(ascii.substring(i), new StringBuffer(), i);
    }
  }


 public static void combin(String input,StringBuffer output,int depth){
      if (depth == 0) {
            System.out.println(output);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                output.append(input.charAt(i));
                combin(input, output,depth - 1);
                output.deleteCharAt(output.length() - 1);
            }
        }    
 }
}
```

Comment: I did not read your comment about generating all possible combination of password, let me think about it as well

Comment: Thank you so much!  This isn't exactly what I wanted but it definitely put me in the right direction.  You're awesome!

Comment: That is all right, I am working on what you wanted right now lol .. I am just free for time being :)

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am very grateful for you helping me out.  I guess I kinda lost my Java touch since I started coding in HTML and PHP again.

Comment: @JacksonWagner, done, Please accept the answer if you like it

Comment: You are the greatest.  I will never forget this.

Comment: If I read this correctly, it can't generate a password with a repeated character.  You likely want combinations with repetition rather than a permutation.  Also, if you modify 'i' to be 3 (to not get an absurd number of strings), it only prints out the set of strings 'a', 'ab', 'ba', 'abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba'.  One would expect it to print out all of the one character strings (90 of them), all the 2 character strings (8100 of them) and so on.

Comment: @MichaelT  I don't think user wanted to generate the password with the repeated character.

Comment: `I am trying to generate a list of every password I can humanly generate.` - this likely includes repeated characters.

Comment: Yeah, repeated characters would be good but I won't ask you to do any more work than you have.  This is more than enough.

Comment: @MichaelIT code has been modified to include the repeated character. Now it is your choice what you wanna use. I am not sure who down voted the solution.

Comment: @JacksonWagner new method has been added, check if that satisfy your needs

Comment: @Ashish Thank you so much for this.  This means a lot to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive problem. so lets use recursion and the power of the sack to our advantage.If we look at an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) we can see that the characters in a pw are from ! to ~ which is 32-126.  Knowing this we can just go through adding one to each character until we reach the last one and keep going until we reach the desired length. you can limit the "allowed characters" and length to your liking. But the amount of possibilities grows very fast so its very possible you will run out of stack space quickly as you increase the number of possibilities.

```
public static final int LENGTH=2; // the length of passwords we want to generate

public static void passWordGen(String currentPass,char c){      
    if(c<='~'){
        System.out.println(currentPass+c);
        passWordGen(currentPass,(char)(c+1)); //go through every character at this postion
        if(currentPass.length()<LENGTH-1){
            passWordGen(currentPass+c,'!'); //start over by adding the current charterer to the current postion
        }
    }       
}
public static void main(String[] args) {        
        passWordGen("",'!'); // kick off the recursion with an empty string and the first character         
}
```